# Can we use MapReduce for other logics except analytics?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, smpp, telecommunication

My project is message forwarding system (We are sending sms to customers handset via MSC, HLR and VLR). Actual workflow is Taking mobile numbers from mysql database and forwarding sms to particular mobile.Now we are sending sms to 20L numbers(customers)/day. Developed by using c and c++ tech. So, If by using MapReduce concept , whether can i split those 20L into two parts and forwarding sms to those splitted numbers is possible or not. Please guide me to do this and please don't get tense if my questions is wrong.

Regards ,
Gunasekar

Answer (score 0):

You would have to move the data from mysql database to HDFS. As mapreduce works on the data which is in HDFS. So you could try these things.

1.Use sqoop and bring the data from mysql database to HDFS.

2.Regarding parallelization, while storing the data in HDFS the framework will split the file and save it based on the blocksize specified(64 MB by default). So you do not need to split the 20L numbers. Suppose your file to be landed in HDFS from mysql is 200 MB, your file will be split into 4 splits(3*64+1*8). A mapper would be run for each split so you will have 4 mappers running. Everything is configurable as per your need. Read Hadoop The definitive guide for more details.

Comment: Of course you can operate MapReduce directly on mySql, you just need to implement the input format for that.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Sorry was not aware before. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Thank u so much @ Vignesh.....Same idea i had,even though i was not sure.. Now i got cleared now.

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut .. Do u have any reference source to connect mysql with Map-reduce

Comment: You named it, look at Scoop. You can use it as a library for mapreduce inputs.

Answer (score 0):

First Understand what is MapReduce,
It is a technique or can say algorithm in which we `map` something to something.

e.g Some word to any number to just keep count and then `reduce` it based on `key`.
Same logic you can apply anywhere.

Hadoop MapReduce makes things simpler by shuffling and sorting.

In Hadoop iself there are many Frameworks which uses MapReduce
Eg. `sqoop` for data transfer between HDFS and RDBMS.

`hive` which runs MapReduce internally(if it's using MapReduce Engine) for querying